# Ionic 2 runs on emulator but not in real device

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I have install ionic [2 template application](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic2-starter-tutorial).
On emulator application runs OK, but on actual device android 4.1.2 I see only white screen.
I have try to debug app with `ionic run android --consolelogs --livereload` but i don't see any error.

What behavior are you expecting?

Application should run on my real android 4.1.2 (LG-E440) device.

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. Follow instructions: http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/getting-started/installation/
2. Take 4.1.2 Android and try to run application.
3. Application should show only white screen...

### Ionic info:

```
Cordova CLI: 6.0.0
Gulp version:  CLI version 3.9.1
Gulp local:   Local version 3.9.1
Ionic Version: 2.0.0-beta.3
Ionic CLI Version: 2.0.0-beta.19
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.0.0-beta.9
OS: Distributor ID:     Ubuntu Description:     Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS 
Node Version: v5.3.0
```

Comment: Having the same issue... Similar issue here as well: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic2-app-show-blank-screen-on-android-device-4-2-2-using-run-command-and-ionicview/39405